# ::before and ::after elements not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

i am using ::before and ::after in css for  and bootstrap accordian css. But these pseudo elements are not working in IE11 although working in all other brosers. What is an alternative or syntax change i need to do so that it fixes the issue in IE11 also.

Below is the screenshot from developers tool IE where i can see css is not applying.

[image]

Comment: ::before and ::after DO work in IE11, IE10 and IE9 - the developer tools is showing what is not being applied to `#Q2Pre`

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo elements are supported with the double semicolon syntaxt since IE9.
Something is crushing your styles.
Maybe use the good old background color to see if the problem is only in IE or not.

Answer (score -2):

I checked my projects, the styles are also crossed out, but they work. Perhaps this is a mistake in IE debuger